# Extract content of body from Postman using python

Tags: python, postman

I'm trying to retrieve a particular code from a body after get response from Postman.
I want to retrieve this id: 00163E7B0F671EDA82E31CA5B621A4B3 and write it to a csv file

The body contents are as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://my344540.crm.ondemand.com/sap/c4c/odata/v1/c4codataapi/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
    <id>https://my344540.crm.ondemand.com/sap/c4c/odata/v1/c4codataapi/CorporateAccountCollection</id>
    <title type="text">CorporateAccountCollection</title>
    <updated>2022-03-15T08:36:52Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name/>
    </author>
    <link href="CorporateAccountCollection" rel="self" title="CorporateAccountCollection"/>
    <entry m:etag="W/&quot;datetimeoffset'2020-02-06T12%3A39%3A34.1278380Z'&quot;">
        <id>https://my344540.crm.ondemand.com/sap/c4c/odata/v1/c4codataapi/CorporateAccountCollection('00163E7AF1111EEA82DBB6D559A072EF')</id>
        <title type="text">CorporateAccountCollection('00163E7AF1111EEA82DBB6D559A072EF')</title>
        <updated>2022-03-15T08:36:52Z</updated>
        <category term="c4codata.CorporateAccount" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
        <link href="CorporateAccountCollection('00163E7AF1111EEA82DBB6D559A072EF')" rel="edit" title="CorporateAccount"/>
        <content type="application/xml">
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

The ID is repetitive in multiple places but the same. Help please.

Comment: You can use Python's `requests` library to preform the request in Python: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Hi Dennis, The link you shared doesnt exist.
Please can you help with the code if you have an example

Comment: This appears to be invalid XML. When I try to parse it, I get the error `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unbound prefix: line 10, column 4`. This is happening because the `m` namespace in the `m:etag` attribute of the `entry` element is not defined in the root element. See [this explanation of namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) for more info. It will be difficult to get the ID from invalid XML - are you sure that this XML has not been altered from the original source?

Comment: @JackTaylor, I have updated the XML correctly. This is the response from the GET method

Comment: I saw you rolled back the XML change. I've reverted back to your second XML format, but I've edited the tags so that they close properly. Hopefully this should be something close to the actual XML that you get back from the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to download the XML content. The URL you provided requires a username and password using basic HTTP authentication, so you have to supply those with the request. The documentation for doing that with the requests library is [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication).

To parse the XML, you can use [xml.etree.elementtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Because the XML document has a default namespace (the `xmlns` attribute of the `feed` node), you need to specify the default namespace when you specify the elements. For example, the `entry` element needs to be specified as `{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry`.

Then, you can use the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module to parse the ID from the resulting URL using regular expressions. And finally, you can use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to write the resulting ID to a CSV file.

I've included some code to do that below. When you run it, you should replace "foo" and "bar" with your actual username and password for the URL you provided.

```
import csv
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

URL = "https://my344540.crm.ondemand.com/sap/c4c/odata/v1/c4codataapi/CorporateAccountCollection?$filter=AccountId%20eq%20%27200148859"
USERNAME = "foo"
PASSWORD = "bar"
XMLNS = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"

def fetch_xml(url, username, password):
    response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.text

def parse_xml(xml_text):
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_text)
    id_element = root.find(f"./{{{XMLNS}}}entry/{{{XMLNS}}}id")
    return id_element.text

def parse_url(url):
    match = re.search("'([0-9A-F]+)'", url)
    if not match:
        raise ValueError(f"Could not parse ID from URL {url}")
    return match.group(1)

def write_csv(path, collection_id):
    with open(path, "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(["collection_id"])
        writer.writerow([collection_id])

def main():
    xml_text = fetch_xml(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    url = parse_xml(xml_text)
    collection_id = parse_url(url)
    print(collection_id)
    write_csv("result.csv", collection_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also, in my code I have hard-coded the password, but this is insecure - it would be better to [store it in an environment variable](https://dev.to/biplov/handling-passwords-and-secret-keys-using-environment-variables-2ei0).

Comment: I get this Error:

HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://my344540.crm.ondemand.com/sap/c4c/odata/v1/c4codataapi/CorporateAccountCollection?$filter=AccountId%20eq%20'200148859'

Comment: The error is because you need to specify a username and password to access that URL. I've updated my answer to include the code for that. I've also updated the XML parsing code to reflect the new XML you provided.

Comment: Also, in my answer the password to the website is hard-coded, but this is insecure - it would be better to [store it in an environment variable](https://dev.to/biplov/handling-passwords-and-secret-keys-using-environment-variables-2ei0).

Answer (score 1):

To make the HTTP request, use Python's [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

To parse XML response, use the built-in [xml.etree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) library. To query the `<id>` tag, you can use *XPath*.

Request example:

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
print(r.text)  # parse your response with xml parser
```

Full example:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
import requests

response = requests.get('https://example.com/your_path')
root: ET.Element = ET.fromstring(response.text)

ids = [id_element.text.strip() for id_element in root.findall('.//id')]

with open('output.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['id'])
    for id in ids:
        writer.writerow([id])
```

Comment: i get empty records for ids from the above code. I have updated the question with the actual exact contents I receive from postman after the GET method

Comment: @Roho The XML you provided is invalid. Use some XML validator to check it and please try agian.